# Concatenating many files into one

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ant

I currently have this command:

```
copy /b *.txt newfile.txt
```

But I want to include all files with folders as well.

- How can I do this? Is it possible to add this to Apache Ant as well?

I also consider doing this to minify JS files.

- Is there anyway to remove lines as well?
- Is there a better command to use than the one I am currently using?

CURRENT CODE

```
<target name="concatenate" description="Concatenate all js files">
    <concat destfile="build/application.js">
        <fileset dir="js" includes="**/*.js" />
    </concat>
</target>
<target name="compress" depends="concatenate" description="Compress application.js to application-min.js">
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false">
        <filelist dir="build" files="application.js" />
        <arg line="-jar" />
        <arg path="C:\yuicompressor-2.4.7\build\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
        <srcfile />
        <arg line="-o" />
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="build/*-min.js" />
        <targetfile />
    </apply>
</target>
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 latest

Comment: You ask if there is a better command. If the one you have is working, I'm not sure what you mean by better. Also, what lines would you want to take out?

Comment: Won't the YUI compressor remove unneeded blank lines already?

Answer (score 0):

On a nix OS you can use:

```
 find | xargs cat | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

This will first find all files under the current folder, than concatenate them and than remove new line characters with `sed` script that adds lines to a register without the new line.

I suspect from the use of `copy` command that you are using Windows, you will have to find the windows equivalents to the nix commands.
`find` for example can be replaced with `dir /s /b`. `type` might be a fine replacment for `cat`. etc.

Or you can have a look in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe that explain how to use nix command tools on windows.